# Java lang Null pointer exception Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

I keep getting this exception with the app crashing each time:

```
Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

at

```
final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
```

The app works perfectly well, but everytime I add this code into this Fragment(Home Fragment), it crashes. This fragment displays all of the user's conversations.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {



    private RecyclerView mConvList;

    private DatabaseReference mConvDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessageDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private String mCurrent_user_id;

    private View mMainView;


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        mConvList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.conv_list);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mConvDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat").child(mCurrent_user_id);

        mConvDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mMessageDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages").child(mCurrent_user_id);
        mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        mConvList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mConvList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
//        mConvList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return mMainView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

            Query conversationQuery = mConvDatabase.orderByChild("timestamp");

            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Conv> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Conv>()
                        .setQuery(conversationQuery, Conv.class)
                        .build();


        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Conv,ConvViewHolder> firebaseConvAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Conv, ConvViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ConvViewHolder convViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final Conv conv) {

                final String list_user_id = getRef(i).getKey();

                Query lastMessageQuery = mMessageDatabase.child(list_user_id).limitToLast(1);

                lastMessageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        String data = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                        convViewHolder.setMessage(data, conv.isSeen());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


                mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

//                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")) {
//
////                            String userOnline = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
////                            convViewHolder.setUserOnline(userOnline);
//
//                        }

                        convViewHolder.setName(userName);
                        convViewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());

                        convViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {


                                Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                chatIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                                startActivity(chatIntent);

                            }
                        });


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ConvViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, viewGroup,false );
                HomeFragment.ConvViewHolder viewHolder = new HomeFragment.ConvViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };

        mConvList.setAdapter(firebaseConvAdapter);
        firebaseConvAdapter.startListening();

    }

    public static class ConvViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public ConvViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setMessage(String message, boolean isSeen){

            TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
            userStatusView.setText(message);

            if(!isSeen){
                userStatusView.setTypeface(userStatusView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            } else {
                userStatusView.setTypeface(userStatusView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
            }

        }

        public void setName(String name){

            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
            userNameView.setText(name);

        }

        public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){

            CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);

        }

        public void setUserOnline(String online_status) {

            ImageView userOnlineView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_online_icon);

            if(online_status.equals("true")){

                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        }


    }

}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.apps.shreya.chatapplication, PID: 10205
                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.apps.shreya.chatapplication.HomeFragment$1$2.onDataChange(HomeFragment.java:148)
                                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzap.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:75)
                                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzca.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:63)
                                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzcd$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:55)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)






 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.apps.shreya.chatapplication, PID: 29056
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.apps.shreya.chatapplication.HomeFragment$1$2.onDataChange(HomeFragment.java:145)
                                                       at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzap.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:75)
                                                       at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzca.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:63)
                                                       at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzcd$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:55)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Here is another Fragment, with almost the same exact code, which displays a user's friends. The same code works in this fragment without crashing.

```
package com.apps.shreya.chatapplication;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mFriendsList;

    private DatabaseReference mFriendsDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private String mCurrent_user_id;

   // private View mMainView;


    public FriendsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

        mToolbar =(Toolbar) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);

        mFriendsList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

      //  if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mFriendsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
        mFriendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    //}

        mFriendsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mFriendsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //return mMainView;
        return mMainView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Friends> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Friends>()
                        .setQuery(mFriendsDatabase, Friends.class)

                        .build();


        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder> friendsRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FriendsViewHolder friendsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Friends friends) {
                friendsViewHolder.setDate(friends.getDate());

                final String list_user_id = getRef(i).getKey();

                mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")) {

//                            Boolean userOnline = (boolean)dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue();
//                            friendsViewHolder.setUserOnline(userOnline);

                        }

                        friendsViewHolder.setName(userName);
                        friendsViewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());

                        friendsViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Open Profile", "Send message"};

                                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                                builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                        //Click Event for each item.
                                        if(i == 0){

                                            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                            profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                            startActivity(profileIntent);

                                        }

                                        if(i == 1){

                                            Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                                            startActivity(chatIntent);

                                        }

                                    }
                                });

                                builder.show();

                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, viewGroup,false );
                FriendsFragment.FriendsViewHolder viewHolder = new FriendsFragment.FriendsViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };

        mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerAdapter);
        friendsRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }


    public class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setDate(String date){

            TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
            userStatusView.setText(date);

        }

        public void setName(String name){

            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
            userNameView.setText(name);

        }

        public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){

            CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);

        }

        public void setUserOnline(boolean online_status) {

            ImageView userOnlineView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_online_icon);

            if(online_status == true ){

                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        }


    }
    //TO HIDE TOOLBAR FROM FRAGMENT
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
    }

}
```

Comment: @KlingKlang I tried putting mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id) into an if else statement as shown in that post, as well as dataSnapshot.child("name"), but both of those did not work.....

Comment: It's an NPE. Which obviously means that you're using an object before it has been created.

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates: The case is that `dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()` is null. Try to make sure that data contained in this snapshot `dataSnapshot.child("name")` is not `null`.

Comment: But the value of "name" is not null, it's from firebase... the same code works in two other fragments but not in this one..

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a constructor class?

If yes then the code to get value is written like

```
YourConstuctorClassName userName = datasnapshot.chlid("Name").getValue(YourConstuctorClassName.class)
```

`String user_name = userName.getName()`

Where getName method is from your constructor class